# Multiple dex files define file from library

Tags: android, gradle

Hey there i'm keeping getting the error

`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/hannesdorfmann/httpkit/DefaultHttpKit$1`

I triple checked if i have duplicate dependencies but i don't find anything...

My dependencies look like this:

`+--- com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1
+--- com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.2+ -> 0.2.1
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1+ -> 4.0.30
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0 -> 19.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30 (*)
+--- com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit-kicker:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
|    \--- com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
|         +--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.0
|         |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.0
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.0
|         \--- org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1
\--- com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0`

which seems fine to me.

build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.2+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit-kicker:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

parent build.gradle has only our maven repository added - nothing else.

The error happens in the library "httpkit".

Appreciate any help.

Tried:

- Build -> Clean Project
- File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart
- deleting build folder
- looking into the dependencies if there are multiple classes but no
- extracted the built aar from httpkit-kicker built through maven and didn't find multiple classes

Comment: You included a JAR too often or from different sources. Check your module's settings.

Comment: definitly not - there's no jar in my library folder and you can see the dependencies there

Comment: I believe you have multiple modules? If not, try to remove the gen folder and rebuild. Fixed the issue for me sometimes.

Comment: which module do you see multiple in the dependency list at the top? using android studio - so no gen folder for me - tried
Build -> Clean Project, File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart and deleting build folder

Comment: What specifically is defined multiple times?

Comment: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/hannesdorfmann/httpkit/DefaultHttpKit$1;

Comment: Please post the build.gradle files for the app and the libraries. Probably not the entire things, but just the dependencies.

Comment: Can you look in which library this class comes from? Can you make sure it's not present in both `com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit-kicker` and `com.hannesdorfmann:httpkit`

Comment: it comes from httpkit and definitly is not in both libraries - the httpkit and httpkit-kicker are built through maven on our jenkins - so there are pom's but it worked fine yesterday and totady got this error, though the pom's or build.gradle hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug/confusion in the latest versions of the tools. The clue is here:

```
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1
```

and

```
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0 -> 19.0.1
```

In other words, multiple versions of android's support library are being loaded, and that confuses the tool chain.

Try to make these consistent. Using the automatic version detection is probably best:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

What version of gradle/Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Actually, no. This means that it detected the same library twice in the graph and it's using the latest, but it doesn't mean you're going to actually use it twice.